# Easiest disk wipe (no cd drive)

Tags: ubuntu

**Problem:** Asus EE (no CD drive) in disuse with forgotten password and personal information

**Question:** How can I remove the content for sure?

Comment: Are you asking to backup (retrieve) the content or are you asking to wipe/erase it for resale?

Comment: KPWINC: wipe/erase for resale.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [**"Linux System Rescue CD"**](http://www.sysresccd.org/Main_Page) and type/run: DBAN (secure deletion) to erase/destroy data from the hard disk.  This runs on a USB-stick too: http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_How_to_install_SystemRescueCd_on_an_USB-stick

Comment: I use DBAN, which is also on the SRD

Comment: Yeah, I think that's what I've ran before... just couldn't remember the name.

Comment: @RascalKing: I have heard about it. Are they the same? If not, which one is better?

Comment: Yeah, they are the same, boot to the SRd, type DBAN (which stands for Darik's Boot and Nuke), and then run through the options.  It will give you a full DOD level wipe.

Comment: I have now the ISO-file on my USB-stick from http://www.dban.org/download. Oddly, it was much smaller than the "Linux System Rescue CD". The other source had the line ------"You BIOS must be able to boot on USB hard disks, and it must be defined before other devices in the boot devices order."----- How can I boot it if I have no passport? DBAN seems to have no instructions about it. Are they so same that I can follow the SRd instructions with DBAN files?

Comment: I found something here:   http://productivelinux.com/2009/03/30/easily-create-a-bootable-usb-stick-from-any-iso-in-ubuntu/
..... it may be easy. sec

Answer (score 5):

Boot Linux from an USB, doesn't really matter what flavor and run:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda
```

If you have two drives or have different drive names, switch 'sda' out for you destination drive. This will write random characters to your entire drive making recovery almost impossible.

Another option is [DBAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darik's_Boot_and_Nuke) (as David also mentioned, kudos) or "Darik's Boot and Nuke" is a open source program, that can be used from a USB drive to write random data over your old data (just like the example above).

Screenshot follows (from Wikiepedia)
[alt text http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/cc/DBAN.png](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/cc/DBAN.png)

Answer (score 1):

Boot off a USB flash drive with Ubuntu, run gparted to wipe the main drive.  I always keep a flash drive with bootable Ubuntu around; they're useful.

Comment: GParted will repartition the drive, not wipe the drive.  If you just run GParted on a drive it can very easily be mounted and read with the right software regardless of the filesystem changes.  I've had to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
# shred -vfz -n 25 /dev/hda
```

This command is available in most modern Linux distributions. It fills your disk with zeros 10 times. Information on the disk can be partially recovered only using very expensive techniques, that buyer of the old netbook, I think, doesn't posses.

Comment: I believe for SSDs, which often can be found in ASUS eeePCs, it's enough to write zeros only once, because SSDs store information without using rotating magnetic platters, as opposed to HDDs

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Billix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/billix/); this is a "super" USB distribution agreggate which provides LiveCD versions of Ubuntu, CentOS, Fedora, and DBAN as well.